# If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with vectors of the form $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ satisfying these expressions,determine $dim(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra

We know $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with vectors of the form $(x_1,..., x_n)$ that attend these expressions:

$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 0$

$x_1 + 2x_2 + ... + nx_n = 0$

and the exercise is to determine $dim(S)$.

I have shown that $S$ is a subspace. To determine its dimension I tried thinking about the linear combination of its vectors, but there are infinitly many of them, so I was unable to develop the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is $n-2$ (assuming $n>1$). In general, each linear equation to reduces the dimension by $1$, unless there are linear dependencies among them, which there aren't here.  One way to think of it here is that you could treat $x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n$ as free, while each choice of these $n-2$ variables uniquely determines $x_1$ and $x_2$ as the solution of a system of equations $x_1+x_2 = C$, $x_1+2x_2 = D$.

More formally, you could set up the system of equations as a $2$-by-$(n+1)$ augmented matrix and row-reduce to find that the rank is $2$, and there are thus $n-2$ free variables in the solution.

You could also think of this using the Rank–Nullity Theorem.  Your solution set is the kernel of the transformation $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1+x_2\cdots+x_n,x_1+2x_2+\cdots nx_n)$.  If you show that this map is surjective, it follows that the dimension of the kernel is $n-2$.